# Confusion about impersonation, authentication, and authorization in web.config

Tags: asp.net, active-directory, web-config, single-sign-on

I'm trying to retrieve the windows login username for the current user in my asp.net website project.

my web.config file has the following items

```
        <identity impersonate="true"/>
        <authentication mode="Forms">
            <forms name="app" path="/path" loginUrl="/path/login.aspx" protection="All" timeout="100" />
        </authentication>
        <authorization>
            <deny users="?" />
                <allow users="*"/>
        </authorization>
```

My understanding is that with this configuration I should be able to retrieve Domain\username from `WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name`.  However, this property returns NT AUTHORITY\IUSR which is the user for anonymous access.  If I am not mistaken, I am denying anonymous access to the site in my authorization section.  What am I missing?

Also of note:

`System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name` also returns NT AUTHORITY\IUSR and `Request.ServerVariables["LOGON_USER"]` returns an empty string, which goes against the information found in this KB article http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306359

I am using .net 4.0 and a windows 7 development environment.

Some resources that led me to this point:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647076.aspx

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306158

[http://forums.asp.net/t/1121780.aspx/1?Getting+a+users+DOMAIN+username+from+a+web+application](http://forums.asp.net/t/1121780.aspx/1?Getting%20a%20users%20DOMAIN%20username%20from%20a%20web%20application)

Thanks for your time.

### Edit

It should be noted that I am locked into forms authentication (windows authentication is not an option), as this is a multi tennant site, and the majority of users will not be using this single sign on feature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using forms authentication then impersonation is meaningless - it only works with Windows authentication. The same applies for Request.ServerVariables["LOGON_USER"].

The reason you're seeing IUSR_ is because that's the Windows account the web site is running as, instead you should use Page.CurrentUser (WebForms) or the User property (MVC Controllers), with no casting. This will return the Forms Auth username.

Comment: I wouldn't say that impersonation is meaningless at all. Do a test like I have in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3632456/iis-7-impersonation-and-identities

Comment: @blowdart:+1 for neat and clean answer:)

Comment: So is there a way to retrieve the Windows login Domain\Username under forms authentication?  Page.CurrentUser isn't a property, and Page.Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name returns NT AUTHORITY\IUSR like everything else.

Comment: There is no Windows login with forms authentication at all, that's why you're seeing what you're seeing.

Comment: Yeah, the more I research, the more I see exactly what you are saying.  I was under the impression it was possible because of Table 1, towards the bottom of this msdn article. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647076.aspx

Comment: Ah if you look at the beginning of that article it does say it's talking about Windows logins. I'll pass your feedback on though :)